# Adding list element via JavaScript gives error

Tags: list, javascript, error, jsom

Please note that I'm doing this for the first time.

I want to add an element to a list via JavaScript. Therefore, I tried this:

```
function fillStandard() {
    console.log("Standard");
    var posInvest = "Invest";

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Position');
    var item = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);
    oListItem.set_item('PosType', posInvest);

    clientContext.load(oListItem);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    console.log("successfully executed");
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log("failed");
    alert('request failed ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

The problem is that my `onQueryFailed` tells me:

```
request failed The field or property PosType does not exist
undefined
```

But when I look at my list `Position` it does have a column called `PosType`:

[image: posType]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using JSOM we need to use the **internal name** (and not the display name of column which you see in the list) of the SharePoint column in code.

By looking at an error you are getting I suspect that you are using the wrong name of your `PosType` field.

Check the internal name of your column by using the method given in below article and then use that name in your code instead of `PosType`.

[Find the internal name of SharePoint column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/).

Also you need to `update()`  the list item before loading it in the `clientContext`.

```
var oListItem = oList.addItem(item);
oListItem.set_item('PosType', posInvest);
oListItem.update();  //Call this method before load() 
                        
clientContext.load(oListItem);
```

**Reference** [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I looked it up, but the internal name of that column is also "PosType"...

Comment: Try using the `update()` method as given in updated answer above.